# Select on hash with indifferent access not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am trying to deal with inconsistent keys (Strings/Symbols) in hashes. I thought that HashWithIndifferentAccess would be the answer but I am getting some slightly confusing results when trying to do some basic operations on these hashes

For example I have the following HashWithIndifferentAccess

```
(rdb:1) metadata
{"indexes"=>["respondent", "brand"], "columns"=>["rating"], 
 "value_labels"=>{}, "column_labels"=>{}}
(rdb:1) metadata.class
ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

when I try the following select I get an empty hash

```
(rdb:1) metadata.select{ |k, v| [:indexes, :columns, :value_labels, :column_labels]
.include? k }
 {}
```

Are all common hash operations available with HashWithIndifferentAccess ? Why is this operation returning an empty hash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you really get with [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) is the ability to set and get values using either a string or a key. Once you start using other reading methods on the hash you move to objects that are *not* indifferent to strings or symbols.

However, `HashWithIndifferentAccess` *does* help you because:

> Internally symbols are mapped to strings when used as keys in the entire writing interface (calling []=, merge, etc)
>
> ....
>
> You are guaranteed that the key is returned as a string

This means that you're always going to get a string for keys with methods like `select`:

```
> h = { sym_key: 'sym_value', 'string_key' => 'string_value' }.with_indifferent_access
> h.keys
=> ["sym_key", "string_key"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Indifferent access means `HashWithIndifferentAccess#[]` will check both strings and keys. However, there is no such patch done on `Array#include?`, which you are using to filter your data. Easy fix:

```
[:indexes, :columns, :value_labels, :column_labels].include? k.to_sym
```